# Is there a way to change the td values in the kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and have numerical values in it. I want to change them based on certain conditions. Like,
if the value is less than 10, I want as a value in the cell.
And if the value is greater than 40, I want change its color to red.
If the value is negative I don't want the '-' minus sign.

Searching for a way to do it kendo, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Please get back if need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a client template for this.

Something along the lines of:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "MyNumericValue",
    template: "#if (MyNumericValue < 10) {#
        <span>#: MyNumericValue #<span>
      #} else if (MyNumericValue  > 40) {#
        <span style='color:red;'>#: MyNumericValue #<span>
      #}#"
  }],
  dataSource: ** datasource config here **
});
```

This should get you going: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template

Additional information about kendo templating: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

And I just found a similar answer here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048848/493557

Comment: Could you please provide me a reference link or something, so that I can better understand and learn about it.

Comment: Hi G_P, can I use the 'MyNumericvalue' inside the span tag(i.e, content).

Comment: @Gowthamss yes, just use the following format:   #: MyNumericvalue #

Comment: My column bound code is MVC based - I'll update the example. If you look at the first example in my first link,  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template , they are using the js version of Kendo and are outputting the column value into the HTML of the client template

Comment: @Gowthamss did this work out for you? If so, can you accept this as the answer?

Comment: Here is how to accept an answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/189173